# Move an image and keep his transparency

Tags: avisynth

I'm trying to move an image, and to keep his transparency. To do that, I have a transparent image, and I convert it into a video with Imagesource. I overlay it to a video made by a completely transparent image. Finally, I want the resultant video to be transparent, and for that I need to merge the alpha chanel of the both videos. Now I don't see how to do that (I encounter the MergeRGB but it doensn't work, I also encounter the Mask method, but I don't want mask of any of my video, I don't want mask of the image I want to move, I want the mask of the moved image). The best I done wast to keep mask of the video.

Please, one of you know how to merge alpha channel so the result will be the alpha channel of the moved image? This is the code I use:

```
clip1 = ImageSource("PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png", end=239, fps=24, pixel_type="RGB32").ConvertToRGB32() 
clip1trans = ImageSource("fond_transparent_720.png", end=10, fps=24, pixel_type="RGB32").ConvertToRGB32() 

clip1 = Overlay(clip1trans, clip1, x=100, y=100, mask=clip1.ShowAlpha()) 

clip1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I used was wrong. Overlay is a method which need a mask if you want to use one, but it doesn't conserve it. The one which is good here is the Layer function.

So I use Layer function and the result is a moved transparent image.